# misalignment in point cloud images

Tags: geospatial, point-clouds

So guys I have a question. My prof gave me a project to develop where I needed to find the misalignments in point cloud image. The main problem I am facing the data he provides us is like pointcloud.fuse and not in .pcd format. So I am confused how to use this file so that I can convert images from point cloud and find the misalignment.
As the file is not in .pcd format how can I use it to extract my point cloud data.
Please help me in this issue as I am really stuck.

Comment: So I don't want to sound rude but why don't you ask your proffesor for more information, who will probably give you more guidance than someone on the internet wich have no idea about the project requirements. Also is it's job is to teach you.

Comment: Can you help me find a formula to convert enu to camera coordinates.

Comment: We used a formula